# How to filter and add together one column using the information of another column, which I need to find using a cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Basically, I want to filter, and then add together, one column('Essay Sentences'!H6:H1400) using the information of another column, which I need to find using a cell(A2).

For example, I have the column **0011c** `‘Essay Sentences’!H6:H1400` and I want to add together only the 0011c’s that also have at least one 0012a. But I only get the “0012a” column from searching for it with cell A2.

A2 could be anything from the header `'Essay Sentences'!F4:AZ4`, so I need the formula to look for any column under these headers.

Also, I need to use the FILTER() and SUM() functions.

Here's what I got so far:

```
=SUM(FILTER('Essay Sentences’!H6:H1400, INDEX('Essay Sentences'!F4:AZ1400, 0, MATCH(A2, 'Essay Sentences'!F4:AZ4, 0)) > 0))
```

[Link to Source Data1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8trrv.png)

[Link to Source Data2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qx7L3.png)

A mock up example as below:

[image: Example]

Comment: I would like to, but I have a lot more conditions in the FILTER() function that I removed for the sake of simplifying the question.

Comment: So instead of `SUMIF()`, what about `SUMIFS()`? You can add multiple conditions and the `IF` acts as your filter.

Comment: It is a bit hard to understand without the context, but here is my unsimplified-probably-way-more-complex-than-it-should-be formula:

=SUM(FILTER('Essay Sentences'!F6:F1400, (IF(A2 = "All", TRUE, INDEX('Essay Sentences'!F4:AZ1400, 0, MATCH(A2, 'Essay Sentences'!F4:AZ4, 0)) > 0)) * (IF(B2 = "All", TRUE, 'Essay Sentences'!E6:E1400=B2)) * (IF(C2 = "All", TRUE, 'Essay Sentences'!C6:C1400=C2)) * (IF(D2 = "All", TRUE, 'Essay Sentences'!D6:D1400=D2)))) / SUM('Essay Sentences'!F6:F1400)

Comment: Can you create a smaller, simplified version of your problem to share? Showing us 20 columns that are not relevant just acts to add confusion. Use some mock data to create a simple problem for US that can be extrapolated to your larger problem! Show us what the output should look like as well

Comment: See the example picture at the bottom of the question, ignore the long formula I typed in the previous comment. I am trying to find an equation that can switch between examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see below solution using **SUMPRODUCT** based on your mock-up example.

The following formula is in Cell `C10` in my solution. You cannot drag it across board as it has been hard-coded to specific **named ranges**. Use **INDIRECT** for more flexibility if needed.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(FRUITS*(SNACKS>0)) or =SUMPRODUCT(INDIRECT($A10)*(INDIRECT(B$9)>0))
```

[image: Solution]

The three formulas are essentially the same depends on if you prefer to use **Named Ranges** (eg. `FRUIT` stands for `cell B2:B5`) or actual ranges (eg. `B2:B5`) in the formula.

Using **INDIRECT** enables you to drag the formula across board but the trade off is that it will slow down the calculation. If you are only comparing one column with another, just use the **Name** or the **actual range** in the formula.